# Number of subgroups of order 48 in $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, arithmetic

I thought it would have sufficed to show that every subgroup of G=$\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ must be formed by couples (a,b) whose set of a's and the set b's form a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ respectively.
By this way of reasoning I should find 2 subgroups one generated by $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and by $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.
But I am wrong since I'm am missing one. I can't figure out how can I concretely generate that one. Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. I think it would be clearer if you explain what do you mean by "missing one". You described 2 groups, which one is the one you missed? Or the missing one is something else?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your argument isn't valid is that not every subgroup of $G$ is a direct sum of subgroups of $\mathbb Z_8$ and $\mathbb Z_{12}$. For example, the subgroup generated by $(1,1)$ satisfies your thinking, but the subgroup of $a$'s is just $\mathbb Z_8$ and the subgroup of $b$'s is just $\mathbb Z_{12}$. This might seem to suggest that $(1,1)$ generates the whole group, but in fact it is (relatively) easy to see that the subgroup $S$ generated by $(1,1)$ is of order $24$, and that there is no way to write it as a direct sum of subgroups of $G$ (since it contains $(1,1)$ but not $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, for example).

To exhibit an additional group of order $48$, note that neither of your examples contain $(1,1)$, so one thing we could try is to find a subgroup $T$ containing $S$ which is not the whole group $G$. Then we would have $|S|< |T|<|G|$, and we would also have $|S|=24$ dividing $|T|$, and $|T|$ dividing $|G|=96$. This, in turn, forces $|T|=48$.

To do this, we should think about what elements are in $G\setminus S$ that we can use to increase the size of the subgroup, but not capture the whole group. For example, $(1,0)$ is in $G\setminus S$, but is a bad candidate since $(1,1)-(1,0)=(0,1)$ would also be in the subgroup, and the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ generate $G$.

On the other hand, $(2,0)$ is a better candidate. $(2,0)$ is not in $S$; indeed, since $12\equiv 4$ mod $8$, the only elements of $S$ with $0$ as the second component are $(4,0)$ and $(0,0)$. Then if we take the subgroup $T$ to be generated by $(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$, then $S\subsetneq T$. On the other hand, there is no way to write $(1,0)$ as a sum of multiples of $(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$ --- since the coefficient of $(1,1)$ would have to be a multiple of $12$ to have the second component be zero --- and hence $T\subsetneq G$. This means that we have a suitable subgroup.

Comment: Note that there are really only two subgroups *up to isomorphism*. This subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_{24} \oplus \mathbf{Z}_2 \cong \mathbf{Z}_8 \oplus \mathbf{Z}_6$.

Comment: @fkraiem, First: nobody asked about *up to isomorphism* but *different subgroups* of that order. Second: how does knowing what that subgroup (the one added by user1306, I suppose) is isomorphic with can possibly help to answer the OP?

Comment: @DonAntonio No need to be so aggressive, I just gave a little bit of additional info, anybody is free to do with t as they please. In particular, this sheds light on why OP's method of just taking subgroups of each component separately failed, it can only give one subgroup in each isomorphism class.

Comment: "Aggresive"?? Oh, dear: I'm afraid you're going to suffer a lot in this site if you *really* think I was being aggresive, @fkraiem